# Checkbox, radiobutton doesnt appear properly on JellyBean devices when using appcompat-v21 and Theme.appcompat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat, material-design

[image: S3 4.3]

[image: s2 4.1.1]

Have anybody noticed this error when using appcompat-v21 and Theme as Theme.appcompat.

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyActivityTheme"/>
```

The checkbox and radiobutton appearances is not correct on 4.1.1 devices and i suspect it is same behavior on 4.0.4 devices as well.

I am not using real device, i used Genymotion in both cases. ( 4.3 & 4.1.1) 
The appearances are fine from 4.2.2+ devices.

If any one knows this issue and how to fix this, please share.

Also tested on real device Samsung Galaxy S2 - 4.0.4. Doesnt appear correctly.
[image]

Comment: It is working perfectly even in genymotion with the versions you defined.

Comment: May i know which device you simulated ? I simulated Samsung galaxy S2- 4.1.1 Observed the issue.

Comment: The same device on which you simulated, Samsung Galaxy S2-4.1.1

Comment: I have reported the issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81495 and is being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat v21 contained a number of issues around backporting styles of components - please update to the newest AppCompat - currently version 22.2